# count row and make max permutation

Tags: excel, vba, permutation

How can I make permutation of name list? For ex. I have 5 names on A column. Firstly count A column and give me only permutations 5 ly to b column in cell with separete "," **changing only the first names**...

Column A

```
tom
Lila
John
sam
steave
```

Column B

```
Tom,Lila,John,Sam,Steave
Lila,Tom,John,Sam,Steave
John,Tom,Lila,Sam,Steave
Sam,Tom,Lila,John,Steave
Steave,Tom,Lila,John,Sam
```

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple one:

In Cell B1 enter this formula: `=A1&","&A2&","&A3&","&A4&","&A5`
This will build a string from all cell values with a `,` in between them.

Then in B2 enter this formula: `=A2&","&SUBSTITUTE($B$1,","&A2,"")` and drag down.
It will start with the value of cell A2, add a comma and then add the string from cell B1 in which it substitutes the value in cell A2 with `""`(no character), effectively removing it from the string.

---

**Edit as per comment from OP**

(Adapt range `A1:A10` as needed)

---

To make this responsive I have added a helper column.
In column B I now have a helper column with the following formula:

In B1: `=IF(A1<>"",A1,"")`

In B2: `=IF(A2<>"",B1&","&A2,"")` drag this down.

In cell C1 I have this Formula: `=IF(A1<>"",INDEX(A1:A10,COUNTA(A1:A10)),"")` This will put the longest string of data into the cell.

In C2 then the original formula, wrapped with an IF to account for empty cells, can be inputted: `=IF(A2<>"",A2&","&SUBSTITUTE($B$1,","&A2,""),"")`

This are then the results:

[image]

Comment: Ok well but I need dynamic 
                               B1=A1&","&A2&","&A3&","&A4&","&A5&","&A6&","&A7&","&A8

Comment: Then you should have made that clear in your question in the first place.

Comment: @ersinmadendere adapted my answer.

Comment: for example ve have onA column 5 names all permutation must be only 5 name

Comment: Was my answer helpfull? If so please consider upvoting and / or accepting it by clicking the checkmark below the vote buttons.

Comment: first answer is well but B1 not dynamic not solve it completely

Comment: How is B1 not dynamic?

Comment: for ex.now when I add a name in A6 column I must add manuel B1 formula=A1&","&A2&","&A3&","&A4&","&A5 it can bee automatic.

Comment: See my edited part of my answer. That deals with this problem.